# Safari plays YouTube videos beyond the end

Tags: macos, safari, video, youtube

I have the following issue in Safari 8.0.7 on OS X 10.10.4 when playing videos in YouTube: The video continues beyond the end of the track. The image and sound stop at the end of the video, but the timer continues to count upwards.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: YouTube]

This is pretty annoying when watching a playlist with music videos. I have to manually skip to the next track when I notice that it's playing beyond the end of the track.

This works fine in other browsers, e.g. Chrome.

Comment: are you using any extensions in safari which might affect this?
does it eventually skip to the next track? or does the current track keeping running for ever?

Comment: No extensions. No, it never skips to the next track - I've left it running for several minutes.